# What is the underlying grammar in the difference between `足らない` and `足りない`?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

Based on the comments from Tsuoyshi Ito's answer to [Translation of 竜すらも恐るるに足らない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4082/542),
`恐るるに足らない`/`恐るるに足りない` is a set phrase meaning "not worth fearing".

Based on my understanding of 一段 verbs like `足りる`, negation will yield `足りない`.

How do I get to `足`**`ら`**`ない` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two verbs: a 五段 verb 足る and an 一段 verb 足りる. They both have the same meaning. According to the Daijisen [[1](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/139289/m0u/)], 足る was the original, and 足りる started being used in the early modern / Edo era:

> 四段活用の「足る」から転じ、近世から江戸で用いられるようになったもの。